# _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) when using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am trying to create and use a `std::shared_ptr` within a class function whose constructor takes in a `std::shared_ptr` private data member (of the same class) and another `std::shared_ptr` created with a raw pointer to the class object (`this`).

Whenever I call the function that creates the `std::shared_ptr` (`foo`), I get a `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)` assertion. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way in which the `shared_ptr` is being deleted, but I can't seem to figure it out, and I've searched all over the Internet. Maybe I'm not fully understanding how `shared_ptr`s work.

Is it not acceptable to create a `shared_ptr` using the `this` pointer, or a pre-existing `shared_ptr` data member?

```
class Containing_Class;

class Some_Class
{
};

class Set_Value_Command
{
public: 
    Set_Value_Command(std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> ptr1, std::shared_ptr<Containing_Class> ptr2)
        : _ptr1(ptr1), _ptr2(ptr2) 
    {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> _ptr1;
    std::shared_ptr<Containing_Class> _ptr2;
};

class Containing_Class
{
public:
    Containing_Class(std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> psc)
        : _psc(psc)
    {}

    void foo()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Set_Value_Command> command = std::make_shared<Set_Value_Command>(_psc, std::shared_ptr<Containing_Class>(this));
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> _psc;
};
```

Here is the `main()` function. When `foo()` is called, the assertion happens:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> some_class = std::make_shared<Some_Class>();
    Containing_Class cc(some_class);
    cc.foo();
}
```

Comment: you need shared_from_this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not acceptable to create a `shared_ptr` using the `this` pointer

Not by itself, no.  And doing so in your example is very bad.  Your `Containing_Class` object is being created in automatic memory of `main()`'s local stack frame, and thus will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope when `main()` exits.  But creating a `shared_ptr` from `this` inside of the `Containing_Class` object will assign ownership of `this` to the `shared_ptr`, which will then try to `delete` `this` when there are no more `shared_ptr` references to `this`.  `delete`'ing an object that was not created with `new` to begin with is *undefined behavior*, and is why you are crashing with an error about an invalid heap pointer.

In order to allow `shared_ptr` to refer to `this`, `Containing_Class` would need to derive from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), and `this` would have to point at an object that is created dynamically and owned by a `shared_ptr`.  Only then can `Containing_Class` call its inherited [`shared_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) method to get a `shared_ptr` to itself.

For example:

```
class Containing_Class;

class Some_Class
{
};

class Set_Value_Command
{
public: 
    Set_Value_Command(std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> ptr1, std::shared_ptr<Containing_Class> ptr2)
        : _ptr1(ptr1), _ptr2(ptr2) 
    {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> _ptr1;
    std::shared_ptr<Containing_Class> _ptr2;
};

class Containing_Class : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Containing_Class>
{
public:
    Containing_Class(std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> psc)
        : _psc(psc)
    {}

    void foo()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Set_Value_Command> command = std::make_shared<Set_Value_Command>(_psc, shared_from_this());
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Some_Class> _psc;
};
```

```
int main()
{
    auto some_class = std::make_shared<Some_Class>();
    auto cc = std::make_shared<Containing_Class>(some_class);
    cc->foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code

```
std::shared_ptr<Containing_Class>(this)
```

you introduce a second `*this` owner, i.e. `command` is the owner of a shared pointer that controls `cc` life. That is the first issue. Yet another, following issue is that `command` is pointing to a stack object.

Usually `*this` is owned by someone and passing ownership to another owner never works.

The current code is impossible to fix due to lack of the code aim.